# how do i correct this regular expressions pattern for php

Tags: php, regex

How do i make this match the following text correctly?

```
$string = "(\'streamer\',\'http://dv_fs06.ovfile.com:182/d/pftume4ksnroarhlslexwl7bcnoqyljeudgmd7dimssniu2b2r2ikr2h/video.flv\')";

preg_match("/streamer\\'\,\\\'(.*?)\\\'\)/", $string , $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Are the `\'`s intentionally in `$string`? You don't need to escape `'`s within a double-quoted sting.

Comment: Eric hmmm ok well i also tried `/streamer\',\'(.*?)\'\)/` with no success

Comment: I'm talking about the string you're trying to match, not your regex.

Comment: @Eric yes $string is from an array and thats how it appears. i did nothing to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $string looks weird. Better to make a three pass parse:

```
$string = str_replace(array("\'"), '', $string);
```

Now we have string:

```
"(streamer,http://dv_fs06.ovfile.com:182/d/pftume4ksnroarhlslexwl7bcnoqyljeudgmd7dimssniu2b2r2ikr2h/video.flv)"
```

Now let's trim brackets:

```
$string = trim($string, '()');
```

And finaly, explode:

```
list($streamer, $url) = explode(',', $string, 2);
```

No need of regex.

Btw, your string looks like it was crappyly slashed in mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I last did regexp matching in PHP, but I think you have to remember that:

1. ' doesn't need to be escaped in PHP strings enclosed by "
2. \ always needs to be escaped in PHP strings
3. \ needs to be escaped yet another time in regexps (for it's a special character and you want to treat it as a normal one)

=> \ as part of the string to be matched must be escaped **4** times.

My suggestion:

```
preg_match("/\\(streamer\\\\',\\\\'(.*?)\\\\'\\)/", $string , $result);
```

Comment: In this case, `"\\\\'"` is the same as `"\\\'"`

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Two barriers to overcome (As codethief says):
1 - Double quoted string interpolation
2 - Regex escape interpolation

For (2), neither comma's nor quotes need to be escaped because they are not metachars
special to regex's. Only the backslash as a literal needs to be  escaped, otherwise
in regex context, it represents the start of a metachar sequence (like `\s`).

For (1), php will try to interpolate escaped chars as a control code (like `\n`), for
that reason the literal backslash needs to be escaped. Since this is double quoted,
`\'` the escaped single qoute has no escape meaning.

Therefore, `"\\\'"` resolves to `\\` = `\` + `\'`=`\'` ~ `\\'` which is what the regex sees.
Then the regex interpolates the sequence `/\\'/` as a literal `\`+`'`.

Making a slight change of your regex solves the problem:
`preg_match("/streamer\\\',\\\'(.*?)\\\'\)/", $string , $result);`

A working example is here http://beta.ideone.com/47EIY